# Is there a better way to Distribute after rule substitution?

Tags: performance-tuning, rule

Here I'm considering a problem related to rule substitution. In the simplest case, it can be shown as follows:

```
expr = x[1] + 2/5 x[4] + 3/4 x[5] /. {x[4] -> 1/10 x[1] + 1/7 x[2], x[5] -> 1/3 x[2] + 1/5 x[3]}

x[1] + 2/5 (x[1]/10 + x[2]/7) + 3/4 (x[2]/3 + x[3]/5)
```

what I want as the result is:

```
expr//Expand

(26 x[1])/25 + (43 x[2])/140 + (3 x[3])/20
```

But in practice, the Expand performs poorly when the scale of the problem goes up, like when I Expand a 10^5 list of expressions. I found a better solution, using Distribute:

```
Distribute /@ expr

(26 x[1])/25 + (43 x[2])/140 + (3 x[3])/20
```

The performance is slightly better than Expand, but still not satisfactory:

```
exprlist = 
  Table[expr, 1000] /. {x[4] -> 1/10 x[1] + 1/7 x[2], 
    x[5] -> 1/3 x[2] + 1/5 x[3]};

Expand@exprlist; // RepeatedTiming

{0.0068754, Null}
```

```
Map[Distribute, exprlist, {2}]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.00453026, Null}
```

I've tried several other possible ways, but none of them is better than `Distribute`. In some sense, I think what I want to do is rather trivial. I'm wondering is there a way to make this process automatic, like temporarily giving `Times` an attribute. But I didn't find such a solution.

So the question is: regarding this problem, is there a better choice than `Distribute`?

*Some background: I'm trying to solve some big linear system of equations symbolically. The equations are of the very specific form that the build-in function `Solve` and `Reduce` perform very very poorly. So I wrote a function myself to solve these linear equations. It already outperforms `Solve` by a lot, but doing these `Distribute` currently is the bottleneck for my equation-solving function.*

Comment: `expr // ExpandAll`   yields what you want  `(26 x[1])/25 + (43 x[2])/140 + (3 x[3])/20`

Comment: @Akku14 On my PC, `ExpandAll` is much slower than `Expand.`.

Comment: Your real question appears to be, how to solve your big linear system most efficiently.  Providing your complete code might yield a better answer.  Also, what works fastest for a short expression might not work fastest for a long expression.

Comment: @bbgodfrey It will not be easy to make the complete code a well-posed question. Maybe I could try later. But this single problem itself is annoying enough. An expression like `x+y+x` is automatically collected but not for `x + 2 (y + x)` . We need to do some real effort to collect them.

Comment: I looked at `Collect` and a few other options, but they were slower, not faster.  `Compile` might help, if you have a "C" compiler.  I do not.  I also looked at much longer `exprlist `, and the scaling remains the same.  I continue to believe that asking for help with your complete code might be more constructive.  Even though `Distribute` is the bottleneck of your code as written, it might not be otherwise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Indeed, I found a better way, taking much less time than `Distribute` Basically using the `CoefficientArrays` function to make the list of expressions and rules to a sparse array, then get the final result by matrix product. In this way, I don't even need to use `ReplaceAll` to substitute the rule.

Comment: I know there exist other bottlenecks in my equation solving function besides this one(I mean the `Distribute` problem). I'll make it a well-posed question if I cannot work it out:D